# How to join two dataframes and create a table counting corresponding values using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, count

I have Table 1 which looks like this:

```
        State   District ID Race    Party
  0     GA      1           White   Dem
  1     SC      5           Black   Dem
  2     VA      4           Black   Ind
  3     VA      4           White   Repub
  4     NY      2           White   Dem
  5     GA      1           Black   Dem
```

Then table 2 which looks like this:

```
        State   District ID Event Type    
  0     GA      1           A; B; C   
  1     SC      5           B; A  
  2     VA      4           A; C
  3     NY      2           B  
  4     GA      1           A; C
```

And I want the resulting dataset to look like this:

```
        State   District ID   # Event A   # Event B   # Event C     # White  # Black  # Dem   # Repub   # Ind 
  0     GA      1             2           1           2             1        1        2       0         0
  1     SC      5             1           1           0             1        1       0         0 
  2     VA      4             1           0           1             1        1        0       1         1
  3     NY      2             0           1           0             1        0        1       0         0
```

I'm very shaky when it comes to joins and creating a resulting table that counts corresponding rows, and I've also never done it using Pandas, so I'm not quite sure how to start with this. Which table would even be considered the left or right table? This is probably a very common use case, I just can't wrap my head around what the line of code (or the SQL query if I was using Postgres) would look like.

Comment: post a sample of your data, not a description of what your data contains

Comment: It's not very clear what are you trying to achieve. Take a look at [Pandas merging user guide: merging and joining](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-or-named-series-joining-merging).

Comment: Hey guys, sorry about that - I updated the OP to reflect some sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we load the sample data. Note I removed spaces in column names to make it a bit easier

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(
"""
        State   District_ID Race    Party
  0     GA      1           White   Dem
  1     SC      5           Black   Dem
  2     VA      4           Black   Ind
  3     VA      4           White   Repub
  4     NY      2           White   Dem
  5     GA      1           Black   Dem
"""), delim_whitespace=True)

df2 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(
"""
        State   District_ID Event_Type    
  0     GA      1           A   
  1     SC      5           B  
  2     VA      4           A 
  3     NY      2           B  
  4     GA      1           A 
"""), delim_whitespace=True)
```

Then we create three pivot tables, one each for Race, Party, Event_Type:

```
dfa = df1.assign(count = 1).pivot_table(index = ['State','District_ID'], columns = ['Race'], values='count' ,fill_value=0, aggfunc = 'sum')
dfb = df1.assign(count = 1).pivot_table(index = ['State','District_ID'], columns = ['Party'], values='count' ,fill_value=0, aggfunc = 'sum')
dfc = df2.assign(count = 1).pivot_table(index = ['State','District_ID'], columns = ['Event_Type'], values='count' ,fill_value=0, aggfunc = 'sum')
```

Finally we join them together

```
dfa.join(dfb).join(dfc)
```

output

```
                   Black    White   Dem Ind Repub   A   B
State   District_ID                         
GA      1          1        1       2   0   0       2   0
NY      2          0        1       1   0   0       0   1
SC      5          1        0       1   0   0       0   1
VA      4          1        1       0   1   1       1   0
```

### edit after change to df2 by OP

If the second dataframe has lists separated by ';' in `Event Type`, it could be converted to the original form using `split` and `explode`:

```
 df2 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(
 """    
        State   District ID  Event Type    
  0     GA      1           A; B; C   
  1     SC      5           B; A  
  2     VA      4           A; C
  3     NY      2           B  
  4     GA      1           A; C
"""), sep='\s\s+')
df2['Event Type'] = df2['Event Type'].str.split(';')
df2.explode('Event Type')
```

output

```
    State      District ID  Event Type
--  -------  -------------  ------------
 0  GA                   1  A
 0  GA                   1  B
 0  GA                   1  C
 1  SC                   5  B
 1  SC                   5  A
 2  VA                   4  A
 2  VA                   4  C
 3  NY                   2  B
 4  GA                   1  A
 4  GA                   1  C
```

Comment: Hey so this worked (although I also needed to supply suffixes in the join statements). However, do you know what I should do if the event type column in the 2nd table is a semicolon separated list like in the OP?

Comment: @archingfork please see my edit. In the future, if you change the question so that answers for the question in the original form do not make sense anymore you should mark it as such, so future readers are not confused